# Calling nodeJS from angularJS function

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have one function which block one room from room list via ajax call here is function

```
$scope.blockThisRoom = function(room, index){ 
 // ajax call an validation
}
```

I have setup nodeJs script

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var server;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    console.log(queryObject)
}),
```

and it gives query object while I am doing testing.

**My Problem** 
I want to call nodeJS script when $scope.blockThisRoom function is call but I am confuse how to call node function.... , should I include nodeJS script as we add other javascript files in my view

**or**

I call nodeJS file a via ajax calling like below is code

```
$scope.testController = function() {
        var url = "http://localhost:8076?id=1&type=block";

           $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
              $scope.students = response; 
           });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular and node are **differents** : NodeJs is executed in **server**, and angular in **client**. So If you try to include node script and run it on client browser, It will just not work... The two are javascripts, but not linked by any ways: you can use angular on PHP projects, and you can use Node.js without angular. It is just the fact that the two technologies are powerful when used together...

Effectively, I suggest to use Ajax call, with parameters you want (use $http.post instead of $http.get if you want to send a long query, or if you want to send arrays or objects... because with node and Angular post, you can send/parse JSON  strings!!)

Comment: So should I call nodeJS method like as $scope.testController = function() {
        var url = "http://localhost:8076?id=1&type=block";

           $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
              $scope.myresponce = response; 
           });
        }

Comment: Yes, or something equivalent

Comment: there is one way to call in via socket.io without using ajax >> function testNode(){
          var socket = io.connect();
          socket.emit('message', 'Message to all units. I repeat, message to all units.')
      }    and in server.js     socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('testttttt : '+data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('test', {'test': 'test'});
    });

Comment: If browser supports WebSockets (IE <= 9 doesn't ;) )
WS is more likely used on the "other way": when you want to notify an user in real-time (for example for a chat), without making it do AJAX request every seconds ;)

Comment: I am new in NodeJS but when we call ajax I can not handle this request, only  I can able to get query string and its params only , can we broadcast message while ajax request receive ?

Comment: @VipinSharma Ajax is just a request to the server, if you want to broadcast use websocket instead (or when your server receives Ajax request, broadcast message so)

Comment: And when using $http.post, put your parameters into "data" property, as object.